# Register a Persistent Handler in Addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have an addon with various modules and submodules. One of these submodules is specifically for handlers. When testing my addon, I noticed that whenever I installed and loaded the addon, the handler within my handler module would not register. How do I register a persistent handler as part of a submodule in an addon? And, how do I make sure that the handler is only registered once, and unregistered if the addon is removed?

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def my_load_handler(dummy):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(my_load_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(my_load_handler)
```

Comment: Why not call `register()` from the other module?

Answer (score 3):

Blender only calls `register()` and `unregister()` on the top-level module, i.e. the file that has the `bl_info` dict in it. You're responsible for calling things on your submodules.

You could be importing a module that handles registration on something wildly different. For example, a `register()` function in some submodule could register a new user here on Stack Overflow. Blender doesn't know which function does which, and thus only calls that one top-level `register()` function.